# make: *** [clean] Error 64 error in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

Here is (part of) my `makefile`:

```
OBJDIR   = ../../../build_project/obj                                           
BINDIR   = ../../../build_project/bin                                           

SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)                                                     
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))                           
TARGET   = $(BINDIR)/project                                                    


.PHONY: clean distclean                                                         

clean:                                                                          
    rm $(OBJECTS)
```

When I run `make clean`, this is the output I get:

```
rm 
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
make: *** [clean] Error 64
```

I'm not sure what to make of this error.  Am I formatting `OBJECTS` wrong?

Comment: The value of SOURCES is the empty string.  Thus OBJECTS is also empty.  Are you sure there are any files matching `*.cpp` in your current directory?

Comment: Do an `echo "THE OBJECTS: " $(OBJECTS) ` instead of `rm`

Comment: Doing the echo is not necessary.  Make prints the value it sees: `rm ` and there's nothing there.

Comment: @MadScientist True, I missed the line.

Comment: @MadScientist Do you mean `OBJDIR` instead of current directory?

Comment: No, I mean the current directory.  You set `SOURCES` to `$(wildcard *.cpp)`.  That will match all the `.cpp` files in the current directory.  Then you set `OBJECTS` to a value prepending `$(OBJDIR)/` to the result of converting each `.cpp` file into a `.o` file.  But, if you have no `.cpp` files then SOURCES will be empty, and so there's nothing to convert and nothing to prepend to, and so `OBJECTS` will be empty as well.

Comment: @MadScientist So, if all of my source files are in `../source` (relative to the make file), what should I do?

Comment: The first thing you should do is include that critical information in your question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source files are in the `../source` directory, then you have to find them there, like this:

```
SRCDIR = ../source

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
```

(we use `:=` instead of `=` here for a bit of efficiency; see the GNU make manual).  Now if you want to put your object files somewhere else you need to convert `$(SRCDIR)/foo.cpp` to `$(OBJDIR)/foo.o`, so something like this:

```
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
```

Now you have to tell make how to build an object in one directory from a source file in a different directory; the built-in make rules only know how to build an object in the current directory from a source file in the same directory (or found via VPATH, which we won't discuss here).  This gives something like this:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
        $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

(this is using make's built-in variables that are used in the built-in rules).

Comment: I meant to upvote this but pressed the wrong button instead, and didn't notice until five hours later. :( Now I can't remedy that until the answer's edited, help (also, thanks :D)

Comment: Thanks! No idea how I got that one wrong, the freakin' buttons aren't even that close together... :(